# CSS Menu hover effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hover effect in my drop down menu but I can't figure out how to do it.

What I want to do is this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

**My Code** - You can also see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eZbyF/1/), [(updated version)](http://jsfiddle.net/6z8GS/)

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="1.html">1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="2.html">1.2</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="3.html">2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="4.html">2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="5.html">2.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="6.html">3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="7.html">3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="8.html">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav {
    float: left;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    color: #6F0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #000;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Working fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/eZbyF/6/)

Change the styles for the below two:

```
nav ul li:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
color: #000;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
color: #000;
}
```

And add:

```
nav ul li:hover li:hover{
        background: #000;
}
```

In order to style the sub-menus.

The first (`li:hover`) you want to set a bottom border - you can change the width of this border from `1px` to something more thick, say, `3px`

Comment: I tried it and it works. The only problem is that I don't want the hover bar to appear in the submenu. Also if you take a look in the updated jsfiddle code the submenu doesn't work now. If i use `margin` and move it in order to be closer to the menu it works but how can I get it to work if it isn't close to the menu?

Comment: @KalPetros Let me take a look

Comment: @KalPetros What is wrong with the fiddle I supplied? My answer, I believe, answers the *original* question.

Comment: Yes your fiddle answers the original question but now after some changes that I made (I moved the submenu 2-3 pixels away from the menu) the submenu doesn't work. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @KalPetros don't quote me on this one - I haven't tested it, but I think instead of moving the submenu away from the main menu, you should add padding to the top of the sub-menu